# Why can't I see a drop in amplitude on a scope when I induce RF on one side of a toroid compared to the other?

Tags: rf

I put various "clip on" or bead toroids on a single wire and introduced a 7 MHz signal into one side of it.  I looked at the amplitude on a dual trace scope and it is the same.

Should it not have dropped significantly?

I am showing the same RF voltage coming out as going in.

Comment: could you draw a schematic or add a photo? I'm really a bit confused how exactly you're measuring. Could you also explain what exactly "introducing" a 7 MHz signal is? Can't introduce a current without closing a loop, so there's no "this" and "the other" side, unless something works as a transmission line or RF component, but this is all just 7 MHz, so practically DC

Comment: 7 MHz is a fairly low frequency for a simple bead; how did you choose the bead for this test; what does its datasheet say about its frequency response?

Answer (score 4):

If there is no load, then there will be no series attenuation.

Beads come in all sizes and ratings. for Z(f) and DCR . In order to be effective the circuit closed loop impedance must be at least 1 or 2 decades below the bead at lower frequencies.  "Any wire" cannot achieve that.

It is intended to be a low loss at DC or low frequencies and lossy at some RF, thus the DCR resistance must be shunted by an impedance at the Rf which you require to attenuate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnxtMQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This would be my Model to demonstrate how to measure a ferrite bead.
[image]